# Highcharts improperly handling negative values

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have created a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amitk7105/fh16Lcz0/) where the percentage area graph chart is plotted using data with a set of negative values.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "chart": {
    "type": "area",
    "style": {
      "fontFamily": "Arial"
    },
    "width": "800"
  },
  "title": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false,
    "additionalProperties": {}
  },
  "legend": {
    "border": "#333333",
    "borderWidth": 0,
    "borderRadius": 3,
    "itemDistance": 20,
    "itemMarginBottom": 3,
    "margin": 5,
    "padding": 10,
    "align": "center",
    "itemStyle": {
      "fontSize": "10",
      "font-weight": "normal",
      "fontFamily": "Arial"
    },
    "itemWidth": 200
  },
  "subtitle": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "colors": ["#67A262", "#67A262", "#FFC110", "#f77b3f", "#61d3f0"],
  "xAxis": {
    "categories": ["12/11", "4/12", "8/12", "12/12", "4/13", "8/13", "12/13", "4/14", "8/14", "12/14", "4/15", "8/15", "12/15", "4/16", "8/16", "12/16", "4/17", "8/17", "12/17", "4/18", "8/18", "12/18", "4/19", "8/19", "10/19"],
    "tickmarkPlacement": "on",
    "title": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "labels": {
      "align": "center",
      "style": {
        "fontSize": "10px",
        "font-weight": "normal",
        "fontFamily": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
      }
    }
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Percent"
    }
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "pointFormat": "<span style=\"color:{[#67A262, #67A262, #FFC110, #f77b3f, #61d3f0]}\">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b> ({point.y:,.0f} millions)<br/>",
    "shared": true
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "area": {
      "stacking": "percent",
      "lineColor": "#ffffff",
      "lineWidth": 1,
      "marker": {
        "lineWidth": 0,
        "lineColor": "#ffffff",
        "enabled": false
      }
    }
  },
  "series": [{
    "name": "Cash",
    "data": [0, 0, 3247037, 4115431, 3649666, 5297250, 4956569, 1625115, 3174121, 6694144, 1512948, 3440926, 683988, 889192, 703447, 2515743, 5878442, 5260639, 2247735, 1696123, 6485498, 1514393, 2055804, 1546508, 1421063]
  }, {
    "name": "Fixed Income",
    "data": [0, 0, 1216772, 1659681, 1902223, 1570967, 1314055, 977437, 887057, 1536891, -653674, -1059915, -1339804, -1071393, -998063, -1200418, -1375094, -1438987, 377989, -133323, 7332923, 12508089, 13924871, 15185459, 15145308]
  }, {
    "name": "Equities",
    "data": [0, 0, 2924177, 7939481, 10863595, 12100681, 16650757, 18639670, 20783963, 17146281, 9656794, 6784358, 7574038, 5126567, 5647696, 2539386, 2750490, 3856696, 4627848, 6936117, 22863720, 19581687, 23265765, 21775318, 22517049]
  }, {
    "name": "Alternatives",
    "data": [11729500, 11896355, 12286734, 12043719, 12763997, 11602665, 9505520, 9005992, 9954085, 11116397, 1982778, 3138404, 3767757, 3899267, 3614944, 5307771, 1708839, 889320, 3074970, 840986, 15276520, 15166745, 15090469, 14700818, 14904036]
  }, {
    "name": "Other",
    "data": [482853, 550589, 627809, 813745, 946673, 1017471, 1101900, 1076074, 1254348, 1230801, 1499999, 1500000, 1631191, 2188279, 2188478, 2254838, 2423621, 2422634, 2432769, 2367905, 4647985, 4530435, 22885564, 23693095, 23706588]
  }]
});
```

Here the Highcharts treats the negative values as positive while computing the percentage.

**Expected calculations:**

[image]

**Implemented calculations:**

[image]

Please help me understand the implementations.

Comment: It's because you're using `plotOptions.area.stacking = 'percent'`. You cannot have negative values in a HighCharts stacked area chart: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27409. If you want that behaviour you will need to write your own logic to calculate the stacks and draw the graph. The short term fix is to remove stacking (although you need to amend the axes) https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/1cm2tfj5/1/

Comment: Just like in the above com - it is because using plotOptions.area.stacking = 'percent'. I did some changes in the core code and see how the chart looks like with properly calculated values - it breaks the logic, because % is more than 100. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/posLvr8w/